# Single N560GTX-Ti-Twin-Frozr-II with 3 monitors?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, graphics, external-display

With a single [N560GTX-Ti-Twin-Frozr-II](http://us.msi.com/product/vga/N560GTX-Ti-Twin-Frozr-II-OC.html#/?div=Specification) card, can I output to three monitors?

and if so, how?

I am currently getting this when I attempt to enable all three monitors:
[image]